# Creating fake IP address Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, random

I am trying to create fake `IP address` using the following javascript random method. But not works.

any one help me to get the correct way to do this?

here is my try: I am looking like ( `"192.168.10.2"`)

```
 console.log(  Math.random(256) + "." + Math.random(256) + "." + Math.random(256) + "." + Math.random(256) );
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The code should be :

```js
var ip = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + 1)+"."+(Math.floor(Math.random() * 255))+"."+(Math.floor(Math.random() * 255))+"."+(Math.floor(Math.random() * 255));
console.log(ip)
```

The code `(Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + 1)` means generate a random number between 1 and 255.

Comment: In my opinion the question linked as duplicate is only similar in some way.